# Xamarin.Android native project : Add TabHost to project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on an Android project using Xamarin, I added a TabHost to my view, inside the OnCreateView then I called a method (SetupTabHost) to setup my TabHost:

```
public void SetupTabHost(View view)
    {
        var mTabHost = view.FindViewById<FragmentTabHost>(Resource.Id.mTabHost);
        mTabHost.Setup(CurrentBaseActivity, CurrentBaseActivity.SupportFragmentManager, Resource.Id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.AddTab(mTabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 1").SetIndicator("Tab 1"), Tab1Fragment.NewInstance().Class, null);
        mTabHost.AddTab(mTabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 2").SetIndicator("Tab 1"), Tab2Fragment.NewInstance().Class, null);
        mTabHost.AddTab(mTabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 3").SetIndicator("Tab 1"), Tab3Fragment.NewInstance().Class, null);

    }
```

My OnCreateView:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyLayout, container, false);
        toolbar = this.Activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.Toolbar);
        SetupTabHost(view);
        bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(() => ViewModel.Title, () => toolbar.Title, BindingMode.OneWay));
        return view;
    }
```

But I got this exception :(

**Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions**

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I would like to see more code from the class where that SetupTabHost is coming from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @Raimo, My fragment just inherits from Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment and implement OnCreateView !

Comment: Can I see your OnCreateView?

Comment: Of course I updated my question and i added OnCreateView implementation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your SetupTabHost() method to the following and let me know if it works.

```
view.Post(() =>
{
    var mTabHost = view.FindViewById<FragmentTabHost>(Resource.Id.mTabHost);
    mTabHost.Setup(CurrentBaseActivity, CurrentBaseActivity.SupportFragmentManager, Resource.Id.realtabcontent);
    mTabHost.AddTab(mTabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 1").SetIndicator("Tab 1"), Tab1Fragment.NewInstance().Class, null);
    mTabHost.AddTab(mTabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 2").SetIndicator("Tab 1"), Tab2Fragment.NewInstance().Class, null);
    mTabHost.AddTab(mTabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 3").SetIndicator("Tab 1"), Tab3Fragment.NewInstance().Class, null);
});
```

Comment: @MohamedAliNOUIRA No problem, thanks for accepting my answer and an up-vote is always welcome as well. :)